# Using the ArcGIS API for Python with a REST service to search content

Tags: api, rest, search, python-3

I have a public REST service that has several layers and feature classes that I want to access. According to the documentation. Once I have the `arcgis` package imported, I can inject my outside REST service as such:
*Note: I am using the Jupyter Notebook to test this code.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS("https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer")
```

Since this is a public service, I didn't have to include any username or password parameters. The service has several layers (item_type="Feature Layer) that I want to access; namely Special Flood Hazard Area Change layer, but perhaps others:
[image]

Using the [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-creating-content/) from the API docs, I tried to do a search in the service just to see all the layers and any info I might need in future calls. I am using the '.search' method from the content manager.

```
# search and list all feature layers in my contents
search_result = gis.content.search(query="", item_type="Feature Layer") 
search_result
```

Every time I try this, I get an either a `KeyError='num'` or a `TypeError: must be str, not int` (if I try to add a query). What am I doing wrong here and what is the proper way to search within this REST service?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer actually came from someone on GeoNet but I wanted to post it here in case someone else runs into this problem. In a nutshell, the mod `GIS` was designed for use with an arcGIS Online account, Portal, or ArcGIS Enterprise Server, not an outside service.

> "According to API Reference for the ArcGIS API for Python — arcgis
>   1.4.2 documentation, a GIS object "is representative of a single ArcGIS Online organization or an ArcGIS Enterprise deployment," and
>   the "constructor constructs a GIS object given a url and user
>   credentials to ArcGIS Online or an ArcGIS Enterprise Portal."  The
>   service you reference is not part of ArcGIS Online or an ArcGIS
>   Enterprise Portal, it is a map service published from an unfederated
>   ArcGIS Server.
>
> If you are interested in accessing the properties of an individual map
>   service, you can use the arcgis.mapping module — arcgis 1.4.2
>   documentation"

:

```
from arcgis.mapping import MapImageLayer
mil = MapImageLayer(r"https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/CSLF/Prelim_CSLF/MapServer")
for lyr in mil.layers:
  print(lyr.properties["name"], lyr.properties["type"])
```

This answer also worked well. Hope this helps someone with similar issues.